# Windows Phone User Login

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am wanting to start programming games on the Windows Phone and wondering what the best way is to log a user in a session on the Windows Phone. Is it possible to do it with XBOX LIVE? Or do I have to hand-craft my own Login system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at Windows Azure Mobile Services (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) to help you out in authentication mechanisms, enabling you to have out-of-the-box support for Microsoft accounts, facebook, google and twitter (it's currently free and you can also use it for more things than just this).

If you don't want to use any external support, then you'll have to have your own hand-crafted login system and somewhere to hold it in (you could also use Mobile Services for that).

If you need any sample code, just drop me a line and I'll try to gather something up. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! If it's a free service it'll be perfect for me. Thank you!